# Is it possible to change default path of node.js command prompt?

Tags: node.js, npm

Just the same as title, I want to change the default path of node.js command prompt from c:\user\"my username"  to  C:\nodejs, but not to affect that one(I mean default path) of windows command prompt.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

[Node.js command prompt default path pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH1s8.jpg)

Comment: If you install node correctly you should have it global, like in any directory node yourCode.js.

Comment: I'd like to ask why?

Comment: yeah..ehh , I know it's global, but i just want to change the default path.
Because I think it's annoying to type cd C:\nodejs\"packagename" in node.js command prompt every time when i am doing the npm package installing.

Comment: @mizok you'll still have to do that as you add to the list of projects you're working on... I use the prompt in atom.io, which opens in the current project directory thus avoiding this issue entirely anyway. I don't think i ever opened the "node.js command prompt" more than once.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to change default path of node.js command prompt, when you launch it, then (Windows case)

1. go the directory where NodeJS was installed
2. find file nodevars.bat
3. open it with editor as administrator
4. change the default path in the row which looks like

   ```
   if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
   ```

with your path. It could be for example

```
    if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "c://MyDirectory/"
```

if you mean to change directory once when you launched "Node.js command prompt", then execute the following command in the Node.js command prompt:

```
     cd c:/MyDirectory/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean changing the current directory once you start node on the command line, you can use:

```
process.chdir("C:\\nodejs");
```

Alternatively, you can `cd` to the target directory first, then launch `node`.

If that's not what you mean, please be more specific.